# Uploading an image to linux server returning 500 error

Tags: php, webserver

I have two server's **server A and server B**
I have a registration page which have **username**,**email**,**password** and an **image**.

I am using a simple php script to upload the image sent from an **ios device.**

I am able to register the new user to **server A**. Image upload works well in the following cases

```
Case 1: Uploading via HTML (Success)
Case 2: Uploading Via app (Success)
```

But when trying to upload the image to **server B (LINUX server)** image uploading failed.

```
Case 1: Uploading via HTML (Success)
Case : Uploading via app (FAILED)
```

I have made sure file permissions are **777**. But still i am unable to upload the image to server. It is returning 500 Internal error.

**Actually, The uploading to Server B used to work earlier. But all of a sudden it stopped working.**

Can any one suggest me what more conditions should i check to make sure image will upload?

Answer (score 2):

Try using CURL

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/path/file.txt'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/upload.php');
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the permission on file alone won't solve the purpose.Make sure you have set directory for `upload_tmp_dir`in `php.ini` to writable by whatever user php is running.
Check with `sys_get_temp_dir()` what it returns,make sure returned path is writable.
If you can `ssh` to your linux server you check the permission on temp directory by following command

```
$ls -ld temp_dir_path_here
```

Of course there could be other problems causing the failure.You can get more information by checking you server error logs or set errors on by copying following snippet at top of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Remove above snippet when done.

Comment: Echoing temp dir is giving some encrypted folder name.

Comment: What exactly it's echoing?

Comment: YuIMg ,when i refresh folder name changes every time.

Comment: Ok `sys_get_temp_dir()` might be returning wrong value due to virtual-hosts problem.Still you should see relavant error in your log. What on page errors saying? Did you check your error logs?Else it would be difficult to tell the exact issue

Comment: Hmm i think its a .htacess file issue.